# How can I change focus backwards when pressing keyboard clear key(x) in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Here's my code, I'm using textformfield. This is for otp input, so whenever user click clear button, I want to focus on the previous text field.

```dart
TextFormField(
    controller: controller,
    autofocus: true,
    focusNode: focusNod,
    validator: (String value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return "";
      } else {
        setState(() {
          otp = one.text + two.text + three.text + 
          four.text;
          print("otp : " + otp.toString());
        });
        return null;
      }
    },
    onChanged: (String number) {
      if (number.isNotEmpty) {
        focus.requestFocus();
      }

      navigation();
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1)
    ],
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      helperText: '',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
    ),
    textInputAction: action,
    cursorColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add  **textInputAction: TextInputAction.previous,** in your TextFormField

```
TextFormField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.previous,
)
```

Comment: I have set the TextField limit to one . so now it changes focus to next field when a value entered. Likewise i need to change focus backwards with clearing the value when clear key ( x ) is pressed

Answer (score 0):

In OTP text field just write this method to navigate back also.

```
TextformField(
onChanged: ((value) {
                      if (value.length == 1) {
                        FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                      } else {
                        FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                      }
                    })),
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?